# Variable not Available JSON Parser data (DataTask)

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I am trying to send JSON Data (An Array of Dictionary) to Server and retrieve JSON String (Simple String Reposponse).
Here is a Code:

```
do
    {

  let serializedData =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: OrderList, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        print(String(data: serializedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
        request.httpBody = serializedData

        //print(request.httpBody as Any)

    }
    catch
    {
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

     let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response,error -> Void in
            print("Request : \(response)")

            let res = response as! HTTPURLResponse

            print("Status Code : \(res.statusCode)")

            let strResponse = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("Response String :\(strResponse)")
        })
        dataTask.resume()
```

And Server Side Code is  (Php):

```
 $JSON_Received = $_POST["user_contacts"];
 $obj_data = json_decode($JSON_Received, true);  
 $user_id=$data_array['user_id'];
 $user_friend_list=$data_array['friend_list'];
```

I have two issues which i can't understand.

1) As api expects to receive JSON Data so when i print the `SerialzedData` to check whether it is correct json or not : it prints something like this:

```
Optional("{\n  \"user_contacts\" : [\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+928885555512\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+925555648583\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+925555228243\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+925554787672\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+925556106679\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"friend_list\" : \"+925557664823\",\n      \"user_id\" : \"+9255\"\n    }\n  ]\n}")
```

Is it a correct JSON i am Sending? as i check online parser it failed to convert the right json. So how can i send correct JSON.

2) When i Print the `datatask` (in Debugger) it shows  `"Variable Not Available"`

SO help me out this problem : Thanks In Advance!

Comment: hi @catalyst i think you should put request.httpBody = serializedData! as it display Optional in print.Second this as see the print value i think you send right json data.

Comment: thanks! i have added ! but compiler force me to remove that. And it is the right data as i already printed before calling this method which send data to server. but here i don't know why it get \n and something like that

Comment: Usually: `serializedData` not with pretty printed. it's useless and add garbage. Try `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: OrderList, options: [])` instead.